# ASP.NET Core 3.0 project fails to run under IIS Express: HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure // ERROR: Unknown command '%LAUNCHER_ARGS%'

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrated a project from asp.net core 2.2 to 3.0 following the migration guide.

After a couple issues were resolved, starting it with `dotnet run` worked fine.

However when I try to run/debug with IIS Express, I get the following error:

> ## HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
>
> Common solutions to this issue:
>
> - The application failed to start
> - The application started but then stopped
> - The application started but threw an exception during startup
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> - Check the system event log for error messages
> - Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
> - Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
>
> For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265

The output window for "ASP.NET Core Web Server" in Visual Studio shows the follwing error:

> ERROR: Unknown command '%LAUNCHER_ARGS%'

As does an error entry in the windows event viewer

```xml
<EventData>
  <Data>Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Path\To\Project\' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '1'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs: ERROR: Unknown command '%LAUNCHER_ARGS%'</Data> 
  <Data>Process Id: 7092.</Data> 
  <Data>File Version: 13.0.19258.0. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: aee5e4080331553ea9dfb7fb388b6d72f715bf6a</Data> 
</EventData>
```

Immediately followed by:

```xml
<EventData>
  <Data>Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Path\To\Project\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message: CLR worker thread exited prematurely</Data> 
  <Data>Process Id: 7092.</Data> 
  <Data>File Version: 13.0.19258.0. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: aee5e4080331553ea9dfb7fb388b6d72f715bf6a</Data> 
</EventData>
```

My initial thought was that there was an issue with my system setup, but a fresh ASP.NET Core 3.0 project runs without issues in IIS Express. I compared the two `applicationhost.config` files of the projects and they're identical (except differences like the project name). I also can't find any meaningful differences in the other project files (`Project.csproj`, `appsettings.json`, `launchSettings.json`). I also tried deleting the `.vs` folder and `.user` files .

The error messages suggests that it's not a problem with my code. As does the fact that there's no exception the attached debugger breaks at and that everything seems to work fine using `dotnet run`. Yet a fresh project created via template runs without those issues.

Comment: Both applicationhost.config and launchSettings.json only apply when running in IIS Express in Visual Studio or via `dotnet run`. Once published, those are irrelevant. Compare the web.config files that are generated on publish with each other. Also, try running the app on the server you're deploying to via `dotnet MyApp.dll`. Ensure there are no exceptions being thrown.

Comment: This happens during development with IIS Express started through Visual Studio 2019 16.3 (with or without a debugger attached).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the issue. One mistake I made was to attribute the `ERROR: Unknown command` message to ASP.NET, when it was actually our application that complained.

The `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` parameter is still passed to the application, but it's no longer set in an in-process hosting context.

More details here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14735

Comment: Can you elaborate on specifically what you did to fix it, I'm running into a similar issue.